API REQUEST ERROR : "Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."
I built a rest API that is used to send SMS messages and emails.
I make an API call and get the following error:

"The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive."}
"Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."

This is my code:
try
{
    var _client = new RestClient("https://xxxx:5000/test/api");
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest("send-sms", Method.Post) { RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json };
    request.AddJsonBody(new
    {
        MessageText = smsMessage.Body,
        SenderName = smsMessage.SenderName,
        RecipientPhone = smsMessage.To
    });
    var response = _client.Execute(request);
    return response.IsSuccessful;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ExceptionHelper.OnlyWriteException(ex);
    return false;
}

It doesn't work only from this project, from curl and another empty project it does work.
What could be the reason it failed?

Can you include the curl command in your question as well as the code from the other "empty project"?

Is there anything in the current project that imposes limits on available SSL/TLS versions? Which versions of .NET are you using for both projects? .NET Framework, .NET Core, .NET?

@phuzi I noticed that curl only works if I add the -k flag, so actually it disables certificate verification no?

Ah, so the error is likely caused by using an untrusted certificate on the API.
